# Database design, for optimized access

Tags: sql

I jump straight into the problem, currently I have a table as such

```
id | model | CategoryId | etc...
```

Now my new requirement is to have support for multiple categories. So I have two possible solutions in mind but I would like to know problems that both this designs might create. I also know that at most I can have 6 categories, also I can't create a linker table to link product to category.

On first design I would simply create column  CategoryN

```
id | model | CategoryId1 | CategoryId2 | CategoryId3 | CategoryId4 | etc...
```

But this would make queries hideous,

```
   id | model | CategoryId | etc...
```

My second approach is simply to add product for N categories

```
   id | model | CategoryId | etc...
   1 | ABC   | 1           | etc...
   2 | ABC   | 2           | etc...
   3 | ABC   | 3           | etc...
```

I think queries would be cleaner but not necessarily simpler.
Another aspect is that I am looking at the performance of the queries and it looks like the first approach would be better.
I hope this is clear enough.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make the CategoryID values bit-field "flags"?

If so, you could keep your performance high by using the single CategoryID field that you have now, keep your queries simple by not adding a bunch of new columns, and would have up to 32 categories for each product over time (assuming that CategoryID is an int).

So, your CategoryID values would be:

```
   id | model | CategoryId | etc...
   1 | ABC   | 1           | etc...
   2 | ABC   | 2           | etc...
   3 | ABC   | 4           | etc...
   3 | ABC   | 8           | etc...
```

You would store the total of all of the CategoryIDs in the CategoryID column (for backward compatibility) and then would have to test the value of the field to find out if a specific category were "set".  Incidentally, you can do that directly in your query as well.

It's not "best practice", which would really require a brand-new table and a lot of joining, but if you are looking for a way to shoe-horn something in there that will work, bit-field flags will do the trick.

Comment: I forgot to say that the categoryid is a Guid so I really can't use this approach. Also how would this work if you wanted to query it?

Answer (score 4):

The third option is a many-to-many table to link a model to a category:

### MODEL_CATEGORIES

- model_id (primary key, foreign key to `MODEL` table)
- category_id (primary key, foreign key to `CATEGORY` table)

Your example data would resemble:

```
model_id  category_id
----------------------
1         1
1         2
1         3
```

This means there's no need for a category_id column in the MODEL table.

Comment: I would love to use this approach but I can't add any new tables to the database. I think I had that originally in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Greg: Of course you can. Talk to the DBA (the strong silent guy over there in the corner). He will be as eager as you to create something useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) here.

Basically, you have a model_to_categories table that matches model ids against category ids.